# Calculating flux across a disk

Tags: vector-analysis, parametrization

"Let $\Omega$ be the solid upper half ball of radius 2, $$\Omega = \{(x,y,z) : x^2+y^2+z^2<4, z>0\}$$ with the boundary of $\Omega$ being the upper hemisphere $S$, $$S=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=4,z>0\},$$ and the flat disk $D$ centred at the origin of the $x,y$ plane, $$D=\{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2=4\}.$$ Then for the vector field $$\textbf v(x,y,z)=(e^z-1,3y+\sin z,1-x)$$ letting $\textbf n$ be the unit normal on $D$ and $S$ pointing out of $\Omega$ calculate the flux of $\textbf v$ in the direction of $\textbf n$ and using divergence theorem or otherwise calculate the flux of $\textbf v$ across $S$ in the direction of $\textbf n$."

I was just wondering if the correct way to go about the first part of this problem is to parametrise $D$ by $$\textbf r(r,\theta)=(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta), 0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$$ to retrieve the normal $(0,0,-r)$ and compute the calculation $$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \textbf v(\textbf r(r,\theta))\cdot (0,0,-r) d\theta dr.$$

Comment: The first part of the question is difficult to understand. Are we trying to compute the flux exiting just $D$? If so, your method looks correct, except that the range of $r$ is slightly off: it should be $0 \leq r \leq \mathbf 2$ because the ball has radius $2$.

Comment: What you say is correct and yes I seem to have accidentally mistyped the limits of integration, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Technically the unit normal for the disk is simply $(0,0,-1)$ and it doesn't depend on r, though of course the conversion to polar coordinates still yields an r. The way the question is structured, it looks like you calculate using divergence theorem the integral for the whole solid, then use that to calculate the hemisphere integral since the volume integral is equal to the sum of the surface flux integrals